# where to find ui components for jeet-grid

Tags: jeet-grid

checking out Jeet currently, having been through their github and resources and wondering whether it has ready-made components such as buttons, dropdowns, jumbotrons, etc. like bootstrap. Don't really want to style my own.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, it doesn't.

**Jeet is a grid system, not a bootstrapping framework**. Don't confuse Bootstrap with Jeet.